Find minima of this function
I want to know if my solution for this problem is correct:
Let $f : [0,\infty ) \to [0,\infty)$ with continuous first derivative. Suppose that for all $a,b \in \Bbb{R^+}$, the area between the $a,b$ is equal to the arc length of the function (between $a,b$) . Assuming $f$ has a minimum, find the value of $f$ at the minimum.
What I did:
We know that the integral of the function between $a,b$ is equal to the arc length integral formula. Since $f$ is continous, by Mean Value Theorem for integrals:
$f(c)(b-a) = \sqrt{1 + f’(c)^2}(b-a)$ for some $c \in (a,b)$.  Then $f(c) = \sqrt{1 + f’(c)^2}$ .
Since the integral is continuous, be can find $a,b$ such that the $c$ is the minimum. We know that $f’(c)=0$ because $f’$ is continuous and $c$ is where $f$ finds its minimum. We conclude that $f(c)=1$
It’s my solution correct? Thanks.

The argument is similar to the correct one, but the $c$ for the integral of $f$ and the one for the arclength integral do not need to coincide.

@JulioPuerta Thanks. How can I correct that mistake?

@JulioPuerta Obviously, making c and c’ different. But how to proceed after that?

I will add an answer.

Take the family of solutions $f(x) = \cosh(x + a)$ on $[0, \infty)$. If $a \geq 0$ the minimum of $f$ will be at $x = 0$, otherwise at $x = -a$.

The argument is similar to the correct one, but the $c$
for the integral of f
and the one for the arclength integral do not need to coincide.
Alternatively, by the property that $f$ satisfies we know that $$\int_0^x f(t) \,dt=\int_0^x \sqrt{1+(f'(t))^2} \,dt$$
for every $x\geq 0$.
Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, by differentiating each side we get $$f(x)=\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}$$
for every $x\geq 0$.
Say $f$ attains a minimum at some $c\geq 0$. Given that $f$ is continuously differentiable, we must have $f'(c)=0$.
It then follows that $$f(c)=\sqrt{1+f'(c)^2}=1$$

Do you need to address the situation where the extremum appears at the endpoint $x=0$?
